# Placing the entire Xserver and GUI inside a cgroup/slice?

Tags: linux, systemd, desktop-environment, scheduling, cgroups

With the intent to guarantee a minimum amount of cpu cycles to keep the desktop environment smooth and snappy,

Questions:

1. Is it doable?
2. Would this be a good idea?
3. How would you go
   about doing this?

Side Question:

How does Linux go about GPU resource scheduling or is that done by the driver?